# How to check if unmount of USB device is completed?

Tags: linux, usb-device

I once unmounted an USB device using Ubuntu or Debian file manager, and when the icon next to the drive that shows it is mounted disappeared I immediately pulled the USB device out. Turns out that Linux was still writing some data on the USB device on the time I pulled it out.

Is this a file manager specific question? Can this happen when you unmount via command-line, too, or does the shell block until the device is save to pull out?

Answer (score 5):

You can always check if data is being written to unmounted device using iostat for example:

```
iostat -p /dev/sde1 1
```

where you specify device (`/dev/sde1` in the example), and statistics refresh interval.

Comment: Just building on this answer, I had to pass the block name, not partition, and the output (to me) is much easier to read by using watch. So, I used `watch iostat -p /dev/sdb` which worked perfectly to see how the system was still writing to my USB stick.

Comment: Do be clear, the relevant value is `kB_wrtn/s` (or `kB_wrtn`), and we want it to consistently be `0`, right (there's no reason for it to be ever above 0 when the device is successfully unmounted)?

Answer (score 1):

For the last question (command line):

On command line the `umount` command waits until the files are stored and the filesystem is really unmounted.  Personally I prefer to use the command `eject` on USB devices: this command will unmount and then power off the USB device (so the led is off and I know for sure I can remove the device).  Both commands will return only when their job is terminated.

In general you can check the led. If it is blinking, data are being stored.  You can give also the command `mount` to see if the device is attached.

Comment: I checked with both `umount` and `eject` that they make programs who are writing to the USB device crash and output "device busy" or similar. When no write operation is running, you might be right. Do you maybe know how I could recreate a situation where not all files were written to the USB device, but the commands `umount` and `eject` work?

Comment: "Device busy" means that some other programs have files (or directories) open in the USB device. Note: a filemanager that is in a USB directory keeps open such directory.  For the additional question: use a USB pen (so slow) and copy a very big file (e.g. installation image of a linux distribution): it take one minute or so to write, so you have time to test umount or eject.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in terminal using `ls /dev/sd*`. If the device file for your USB drive still exists, then probably it is still writing some data.

Comment: I unmounted a USB device with `sudo umount /dev/sdXn`, but it is still listed with `ls /dev/sdX*`, even though nothing is being written to the USB device.

Comment: Try detach using udisks (you should install it first though) with `sudo udisks --detach /dev/sdX`

Comment: After an umount the device should be still there.  For harddisk it is common to umount and mount the same device/partition without rebooting.  The device will disappear only if an eject is given, after the umount.